# how to resolve HTTP Status 500: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, maven, classloader, jira, jira-plugin

When i use library(`com.sun.jersey.client.apache.config.DefaultApacheHttpClientConfig or another` ) returns status 500 with massage

> "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/sun/jersey/client/apache/config/DefaultApacheHttpClientConfig...",

which means that program don't see this library at runtime(program is a jira plugin which runs on localhost). How i can add this library dynamically to runtime, cause when i build classes at my PC its OK. I tried to configure pom.xml and `atlassian-plugin.xml` files.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11961749/jira-rest-java-client-missing-apachehttpclientconfig-from-jersey

Answer (score 0):

Download the `jersey-apache-client.jar` with all the dependencies and add it to your classpath.